# Select SQL using c# error can someone guide this one

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

What I'm missing?
I've got error:

> Sqlexception was unhandled by usercode

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
SqlCommand objCmd;
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dtReader;
String strSQL;
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'";

objCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

//*** BindData to GridView ***//
GridView3.DataSource = dtReader;
GridView3.DataBind();

dtReader.Close();
dtReader = null;
```

Comment: What is the error and remove the typo " ' " from your query.

Comment: dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader(); error this line

Comment: Tip: See [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: what is the exception, not on which line. Remove the ' symbol from the query.

Comment: Your code works fine, your query has problem. Remove the " ' " at the end of strSQL = "SELECT * FROM "+DropDownList1.SelectedValue+"'";

Comment: and how can i sent value at  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM "+DropDownList1.SelectedValue+"'";

Comment: Use strSQL = "SELECT * FROM "+DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

Comment: Now ,  I got error at GridView3.DataSource = dtReader;
        GridView3.DataBind();

Comment: Shall we guess what the error is, or will you share it?

Comment: thank you for help error this invalidOperationExceoption  at gridview3.databind();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ,

```
  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

ie., just remove ' from the query string.

Then add the following code at the end.

```
GridView3.DataSource = dtReader;
GridView3.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
GridView3.DataBind();
```

Comment: i got error at gridview3.databind  error MSG is invalidOperationException was unhandled by user code

Comment: @KaneSmithSillapasit What are the values inside the DropDownList control?

Comment: name of table string value

Comment: thx it work GridView3.DataSource = dtReader;
GridView3.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
GridView3.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

this code works now

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
SqlCommand objCmd;
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dtReader;
String strSQL;
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue ;

objCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
dtReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

GridView3.DataSource = dtReader;
GridView3.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
GridView3.DataBind(); 

dtReader.Close();
dtReader = null;
```